# how can i find Spectral Acceleration (Sa(T1; 5%))?

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, software, acceleration, seismic

I want to do incremental dynamic analysis (IDA) for my project and for hunt and fill algorithm i need the 5% damped Spectral Acceleration at the structure’s first-mode period (Sa(T1; 5%)) . Can i find it by using Seismosignal software directly ? if not how can i calculate Sa(T1; 5%) ?

Answer (score 0):

ASCE 7-16  Section 11.4.5 provides the equations for the 5 percent damped spectral response acceleration, Sa, relative
to period, T, in the following range.

0 ≤ T < T0, T0 ≤ T ≤ TS, TS < T ≤ TL, and TL < T

here is a link to a detailed solved example. look at Example 2, how to create design spectra with 5% damping. Except that the link, they have for the USDS application is dead use this link instead, [find USDS data from address](https://hazards.atcouncil.org/#/)to read Ss and S1 and other dates then
use them to plug in this ASCE 7-16 example 2.

[use example 2. open first](https://shop.iccsafe.org/media/wysiwyg/material/9011S121-sample.pdf)